# Symfony debugbar is hidden on templateaction

Tags: php, symfony, debugging

I have an event listener that is getting fired `onKernelRequest`. That listener checks if the request comes from a mobile device. If not, it returns a template as a response.

Thats the check:

```
if(!$this->browserHelper->isMobile() && !in_array($routeName, $routes) && (false === strpos($routePath, '/admin'))) {
  $event->setResponse($this->templateController->templateAction('frontend/staticPage/only-mobile.html.twig'));
}
```

Now my debugbar gets hidden and the console outputs

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null

If I comment that `if` body out, everything works fine. The strange thing is that even if the `if` is false, the error occures.

How can I fix this?

---

Edit: I have localised that error to the `$event->setResonse()`, `$event` is `GetResponeEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the twig file `frontend/staticPage/only-mobile.html.twig` to another one? The debug toolbar can only be displayed if there is  and  tag in your html, it may help to know with a minimalist twig file.

You may have more details with the last request here : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/_profiler/search?limit=10`

By the way, I prefer to use a redirection `new RedirectController` than render a template directly from the listener. It may be skirt the issue.